# Decreasing the size of google maps sdk for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

i dowloaded google maps sdk (1.8.1) for ios,I'm using it in my app.But what i noticed is that size of the framework is about 55MB.Is there any way to decrease the size of framework.
A file named "A" in directory structure "GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A" is about 54MB.Is google maps depended on this file.please suggest some help.

Comment: Don't work about the framework size. Worry about the final size of your ipa.

Comment: does it affect ipa size,my project size is 78MB,plz help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Keep GoogleMap framework outside of the project and just drag it in your project without copy file. It will reduce the file size. Only bundle file keep inside of your project.

Comment: This will not work if the user submits the application to the store.

Comment: this is bogus ;)

Answer (score 2):

a framework is bound to be larger than the compiled in code thats ending up in your ipa.

- the framework has the code for N architectures, the headers and the resources
- what you will use in the end is the code for 1 architecture and the resources

As far as I can remember it adds about about 1mb to your ipa

---

they now ship bitcode as the iPad is compiled on apple's side for each customer.

Comment: I have removed apple map and add Google map through pod thats increase my 'ipa' size (from 2.7 mb to 9.5mb) nearly 7 mb.

Comment: they now ship bitcode as the iPad is compiled on apple's side for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/Current
ls -lh GoogleMaps # 113 MB
```

If you don't support phones higher than the iPhone 5:

```
lipo -remove arm_v7 GoogleMaps -o GoogleMaps
```

If your development machine is a 64 bit machine:

```
lipo -remove i386 GoogleMaps -o GoogleMaps
```

And then:

```
ls -lh GoogleMaps # 75MB
```