# size of iOS app in relation to project size

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm making an iOS app on XCode and the project folder size was small, ~ 1MB. Then I needed a screen which showed some information and markers on a map, so I used [Google Maps for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start). This required me to add the Google maps framework into my project folder, so now the size is ~50MB. Will the size of the app be this huge? I have searched a LOT, and I can't find a way to check the size of my app without subscribing to the Apple Developer's Program (I am not ready to pay 99$ a year yet) and I do not have sudo privileges as well (I am trying out iOS app dev using a [Mac in Cloud](http://www.macincloud.com/), it is not my own Mac).

I know it is a slightly stupid question, but I can't find solutions anywhere. If you feel compelled to downvote please at least leave a comment as to why you are doing so.

Comment: I recently told somebody on SO that this is not the case -- so you couldn't have searched a lot ;) google adds a a few mb (~4 or so to you app size)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197994/decresing-the-size-of-google-maps-sdk-for-ios/24199455#24199455

Comment: @Daij-Djan Alright thanks, I hadn't found this

Answer (score 1):

You can check the app size to following path:

`/Users/saurav.nagpal(User)/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/yourAppFolder/ProductName`

It gives you exact size of your application.

Comment: good advice -- this wasn't the question though ;) anyways UPVoting

Comment: in iPhone Simulator/7.1 I have the following folders:Applications Documents Media  tmp
Containers Library  Root  var, can't find my application folder

Comment: Sorry i missed "Applications" in application go to your app folder it is something like that "2A768440-F9A8-41A4-BE50-A6DE93C5E084". I edit the path now

Comment: @SauravNagpal Yeah I found it, turns out all the files together inside it are ~800KB :) Is it actually that small? According to DaijDjan's comment on the question, approximately 4 MB should be added by google maps