# Including Google.Framework into my bundle file?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a question. I have downloaded google's latest SDK for ios from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

It is a whopping 64MB file.

According to the instruction on the page itself, it says i have to include the GoogleMaps.framework inside my project and copy files if needed.

However, does it mean that the while file GoogleMaps.frameworl (64MB) will be included inside the bundle file when I submit my project online?

If not what is the exact way to do it?

Thank you very much.

PS
I browsed through this [Decreasing the size of google maps sdk for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197994/decreasing-the-size-of-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)
However, I am still confuse. What exactly is the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to the steps from the `getting started` page. And yes, your uncompressed application will get 64 more megabytes. There's no other workaround for adding a non-apple framework to an iOS app (like using a shared location for frameworks).

However `ipa` files are zipped versions of your app bundle, so the total size of your app will reduce (how much it depends on how well the files in your bundle can compress). Also the [2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199455/1974224) from the question you posted mentions that the strip of other architectures when the `ipa` is generated, so the final size of your app will not increase that much.

Comment: thank you. I have tried to created the ipa files, and i am glad it is just a few MB extra. For reference to create ipa files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6